QGIS atlas minimap link to page (PDF)
I'm using QGIS 3.80

I've made an atlas of my city.
One page corresponds to one item of my grid.
A mini map shows where I am in the current map.
I'll export it to PDF

Is it possible to create links in my mini map?
I'd like to click on an item of my grid shown in the mini map to go to the page.

Do you want to create a PDF with a page for each grid square, and then be able to click on grid square in the mini-map and have it bring you to the correct page for that grid square in the PDF?

absolutely, yes

I have come up with a bit of a hacky solution.
The PyQGIS script below creates a grid of label items over your map grid. In each label is a hyperlink that when clicked will jump to the corresponding page of the PDF.
If you have only a few grid cells, it may be easier to place and configure them manually, otherwise use the script to generate the label grid.
Note, it only works once the layout has been saved as a PDF. Clicking the hyperlinks in the layout does nothing.
Before running the script, you will need to determine the starting X and Y positions of your map grid and the width and height of the cells (in millimetres, not geographical units). This can easily be achieved by manually placing a label over the first grid cell and checking the item properties.


Once you have these values, update the relevant values in the script start_x, start_y, width, and height. These values must be integers, which is why I rounded them up in the script.
As it is, the script will produce black squares (Wingdings character n) in each label. You will need to adjust the font size and the margin size in the script to suit your layout.

Once you are happy with the placement, the font colour can be made transparent by adjusting the alpha value in the hex code in the HTML.
label_item.setText(f'<a href="#page={page_reference}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF000000;">n</a>')

can be changed to
label_item.setText(f'<a href="#page={page_reference}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #00000000;">n</a>')

p = QgsProject.instance()

manager = p.layoutManager()

# change for the name of your layout
layout = manager.layoutByName('pdf test')

# define the starting parameters for the first grid cell
start_x = 37.0
start_y = 52.0
width = 50
height = 50

# define number of rows and columns in the grid
num_rows = 2
num_columns = 2

# the number of the page the first grid cell should jump to
page_reference = 2

for row in range(num_rows):
    for col in range(num_columns):
        
        # for each row and colum, create a label item
        label_item = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
        
        # specifiy the size for the label so it matches the grid cells
        label_item.setFixedSize(QgsLayoutSize(width, height))
        
        # center align the text in the label
        label_item.setHAlign(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        # trigger HMTL rendering
        label_item.setMode(1)
        
        # create a textFormat object and define some options
        text_format = QgsTextFormat()
        text_format.setAllowHtmlFormatting(True)
        text_format.setFont(QFont('Wingdings'))
        
        # adjust the font size so that the character covers a good amount of the grid cell
        text_format.setSize(200)
        label_item.setTextFormat(text_format)
        
        # insert a hyperlink into the label to jump to the corresponding page 
        # `text-decoration: none` removes the default hyperlink formatting and allows the text to be styled (i.e. made transparent)
        # Wingdings character `n` displays as a filled square
        label_item.setText(f'<a href="#page={page_reference}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FF000000;">n</a>')
        
        # the upper margin might need to be adjusted to fit the character in the grid cell properly
        label_item.setMarginY(-12)
        
        # shift the label to overlay the corresponding grid cell
        label_item.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(start_x + width * col, start_y + height * row), QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)
        
        # add the label to the layout
        layout.addItem(label_item)
        
        # increment the page number that will be jumped to
        page_reference += 1

Result:

The Back to grid "button" is a label with the text <a href="#page=1">Back to grid</a>. Don't forget to the activate the option Render as HTML.

